# I am running a while loop which ends in & and I closed the terminal, so I can't stop it now

Tags: terminal

This is the code

```
while sleep 1; do say "1"; done &
```

I closed the terminal, but now I can't stop my Mac saying "one" every second.
It is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

- Open a new Terminal tab/window
- Run `ps alx|grep "[s]leep 1"` (maybe several times, until you get the `sleep 1` as part of the output

  ```
  pse@Mithos:~$ ps alx|grep sleep 1
    502  1268  1245   0  20  0  2432796   1460 -      S      ??    0:00.00 sleep 31536000
    502 80121   809   0  31  0  2432796   1772 -      S+   s002    0:00.00 sleep 1
  ```
- Kill the shell it's running in by using the parent PID of the sleep command (the number in the third column, `809` in this case): `kill -HUP YOUR-PARENT-PID-HERE`

Comment: it says: grep: 1: No such file or directory

Comment: @Cemre Suler, Use: `ps alx | grep "[s]leep 1"`

Comment: and how to kill the progress now?

Comment: @CemreSuler See the third item in the answer: `kill -HUP [ppid]` where `[ppid]` is the number you get as described in the answer.

Comment: @Cemre Suler, I would just use `kill -HUP "$(pgrep sleep)"` and not bother with: `ps ...`

Comment: @user3439894 It's not enought to kill `sleep`, the loop will just iterate. You need to kill the shell process executing the loop.

Comment: @patrix, I executed `while sleep 1; do say "1"; done &` and closed Terminal as stated in the OP and it killed everything, so I open Terminal and again executed what was in the OP leaving Terminal open this time.  Then in another Terminal I executed `kill -HUP "$(pgrep sleep)"` and that was that no more 1 every second. If it doesn't work that way for you then the OP has omitted something as closing Terminal should have killed the  `while loop` to begin with.

Comment: @user3439894 Actually I only tried without the `&` part, so if it works with `pgrep` even the better :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go into Terminal and run `ps aux | grep sleep` and you should be able to see your while command as a result.  Note the grep will also show up.  Find the PID of the process and key in `kill [pid]`.  If it fails then `kill -9 [pid]` note in place of the brackets actually use the number of the process, without the brackets.

Comment: This just kills the `sleep` process once, not the loop. And with only one second of sleep time, the most likely output will be `-bash: kill: ([pid]) - No such process`